# Robot Framework with Appium Library: take actions depending on current Page

Tags: robotframework

My robot framework test is testing a mobile app that does Bluetooth stuff. The Bluetooth stuff is not very stable.

Because of this, I want to introduce a number of retries before failing. I know about this:

```
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    5x    10s    Keyword
```

The problem is this: depending on success or failure of the previous Bluetooth command (or if it is the first attempt), the app is in different pages.

To solve this, I would like to start the Bluetooth command attempt with:

1. looking if we are at the correct page
2. pressing back if not

Reading the doc for [Appium Library for Robot Framework](https://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html#Page%20Should%20Contain%20Text), I only found the `Page Should * Contain` keywords. These *fail* the test if the page is not correct. I don't want to fail, I want to take action.

How can I do something like this?

```
Run Keyword If
...    Page Does Not Contain Text     ${my_page_text}
...    Click Back
Page Should Contain    ${my_page_text}
```

Answer (score 0):

The technique we use, is to avoid failing the keywords, by using `Run Keyword and Return Status` or `Run Keyword and Ignore Error`.

Something like:

```
${text_OK}=    Run Keyword and Return Status    Page Should Contain    ${my_page_text}
Run Keyword If    not ${text_OK}    Click Back
```